# send email to users from a batch job

Tags: apex, email, batch

I have a batch process that is sending emails to Users.  Is there a limit on the number of emails that I can send to users thru a batch process?

Here is my batch code:

```
global class InventoryWishlistNotifyBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

public string query = 'select Id, Owner.Email, Year__c, Make__c, Model__c, Color__c, Account__r.Name, Account__c from Inventory_Wishlist__c where Record_Status__c = \'Open\'';

global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, Sobject[] scope)
{   
    Map<Inventory_Wishlist__c, Product2> temp = new Map<Inventory_Wishlist__c, Product2>();

    EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [select Id, Body  from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'Inventory_Wishlist_Match_Found'];

    for (Inventory_Wishlist__c item : (List<Inventory_Wishlist__c>)scope) {
        for(Product2 prod : getProducts()) {
            if(item.Make__c.trim().toLowerCase() == prod.Make__c.trim().toLowerCase() && 
                item.Model__c.trim().toLowerCase() == prod.Model__c.trim().toLowerCase() && 
                    item.Year__c.trim().toLowerCase() == prod.Year__c.trim().toLowerCase()) {
                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                        email.setToAddresses(new String[] {item.Owner.Email});
                        email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                        email.setTargetObjectId(item.OwnerId);
                        email.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id);
                        email.setWhatId(item.Id);
                        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
                        item.Record_Status__c = 'Closed';
                        temp.put(item, prod);   
            }
        }   
    }
    if(!temp.isEmpty() && temp.size() > 0) {
        List<Inventory_Wishlist__c> itemsToUpdate = new List<Inventory_Wishlist__c>();
        itemsToUpdate.addAll(temp.keyset());
        update itemsToUpdate;
    }       
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

}

private List<Product2> getProducts() {
    return [select Id, Make__c, Model__c, Year__c, Color__c from Product2 where Make__c != null AND Model__c != null AND Year__c != null];
}
}
```

I have a nested loop where I'm scanning all products based on each item in my outer loop which is my scope.  If I find a match, I'm sending the email.

Is there a more streamlined approach to scan the products, find a match and send the email?

If the emails are going to internal salesoforce users, does the 1000 emails a day limit apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There’s no limit on sending individual emails to contacts, leads, person accounts, and users in your organization directly from account, contact, lead, opportunity, case, campaign, or custom object pages.

see http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm